# How can I mask bits?

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, bit, mask

I have a byte, whose value in binary is 11111111. I have to extend my byte to 16 bits 0101010101010101 according to these rules: if bit = 1, now is 01. If bit = 0, now is 10.

For example:

```
00001111 -> 1010101001010101
00000101 -> 1010101010011001
```

What is the operation to do this?

Comment: Why are you masking a byte with a 16-bit mask? Do you plan on casting your byte entity into a 16-bit word?

Comment: You realize a byte (typically, now days) has only 8 bits right. How do you plan on growing your bytes?

Answer (score 1):

First, convert your byte to an int:

```
int x = (int)byte_value;
```

Then, extend to 16 bits, by shifting bits 4 at a time, then 2, then 1, then doubling each bit with a shift and bitwise OR:

```
x = ((x << 4) | x) & 0b0000111100001111;
x = ((x << 2) | x) & 0b0011001100110011;
x = ((x << 1) | x) & 0b0101010101010101;
x = (x << 1) | x;
```

Then, mask the bits so that the even bit positions are 1 if the bit is 1, and the odd positions are 1 if the bit is 0 (using bitwise NOT):

```
x = (x & 0b0101010101010101) | (~x & 0b1010101010101010);
```

Comment: Beware: if ever the byte_value is signed char, then conversion to int will perform sign extension and might populate all but low 8 bits with 1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is an operator for "expanding" bits as described.
But you could do it in a loop together with shifting and testing bits as follows:

```
unsigned char b = 0xff;
unsigned int result = 0x0;

for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    result <<= 2;  // make place for the next 2 bits

    int isSet = b & 0x80; // check highest significant bit of b
    if (isSet) {
        result |= 0x01;  // in bits: 01
    }
    else {
        result |= 0x02; // in bits: 10
    }

    b <<= 1;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's it! Thankss

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem...